# Flutter: Cubit no refresca el widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy desarrollando el juego del sudoku para aprender flutter. Estoy intentando hacer que al señalar una casilla del tablero de sudoku, ésta se pinte de verde. Esto lo realizo mediante cubit para guardar el estado de todo el juego.

Sospecho que fue al cambiar los widgets que se rompió esta funcionalidad porque antes funcionaba con un Table en vez de con Columns y Rows.

Os muestro el código a continuación:

En PlayScreen es donde inicializo el cubit con los datos del juego porque es la pantalla que va a mostrar el tablero y la botonera.

```
class PlayScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final int level;
  const PlayScreen({Key? key, required this.level}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => sl<GameCubit>()..initialState(level),
      child: BlocBuilder<GameCubit, Game>(builder: (context, game) => WillPopScope(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Sudoku'),
            ),
            backgroundColor: primaryBackgroundColor,
            body: Column(
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: SudokuBoard(),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: KeyPad(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ))
    );

  }
}
```

En SudouBoard es donde genero el tablero del juego

```
class SudokuBoard extends StatelessWidget {
  const SudokuBoard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(9, (int rowNumber ) {
        return _getRow(context, rowNumber);
      })
    );
  }


  Widget _getRow(BuildContext context, int row) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(9, (int col) {
          return Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: SudokuCell(row: row, col: col)
            ),
          );
        })
      )
    );
  }
}
```

En SudokuCell es donde se genera cada casilla con los datos correspondientes:

```
class SudokuCell extends StatelessWdget {
  final int row, col;

  const SudokuCell({Key? key, required this.row, required this.col}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BlocBuilder<GameCubit, Game>(
      builder: (context, game) {
        var cell = game.board!.cells[row][col];
        var ss = cell.cellStatus;
        return InkResponse(
          enableFeedback: true,
          onTap: () {
            if (!cell.initial) {
              BlocProvider.of<GameCubit>(context, listen: false)
                  .setPosition(row, col);
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: cell.initial ? Colors.grey : getColorCellByStatus(cell),
              border: Border(
                right: BorderSide(
                  width: (col % 3 == 2) ? 2.0 : 1.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  width: (row % 3 == 2) ? 2.0 : 1.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                top: BorderSide(
                  width: (row == 0) ? 2.0 : 1.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                left: BorderSide(
                  width: (col == 0) ? 2.0 : 1.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                cell.value.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight:
                      cell.initial ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    );
  }

  Color getColorCellByStatus(Cell cell){
    switch (cell.cellStatus) {
      case CellState.selected:
        return Colors.lightGreen;
      case CellState.error:
        return Colors.red;
      default:
        return Colors.white;
    }
  }
}
```

La llamada a la función del cubit la realiza perfectamente.

```
class GameCubit extends Cubit<Game> {
  //TODO quitar _board cuando vaya dinamico
  late Board _board;

  GameCubit(this._persistenceRepository, this._gameRepository) : super(Game(id: '0', initialBoard: Board(cells: []), gameStatus: GameState.initial, selectedRow: -1, selectedCol: -1));
  final GameLocalDataSource _persistenceRepository;
  final GameRepository _gameRepository;

  Future<void> initialState(int level) async {
    //editado 2 -->
    _board = Board(cells: _getInitialBoard());
    Game game = Game(id: '0',initialBoard: _board, board:_board,gameStatus: GameState.initial, selectedRow: -1, selectedCol: -1);
    
    
    emit(game);
  }

// editado -->
void setPosition(int row, int col){

    _board = state.board!;
    if (state.selectedRow != -1 && state.selectedCol != -1){
      _board.cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol].cellStatus = CellState.none;
    }

    _board.cells[row][col].cellStatus = CellState.selected;
    Game game = state.copyWith(
      board: _board,
      selectedRow: row,
      selectedCol: col
    );

    emit(game);
  }


void setSelectedCell(int num){
    List<List<Cell>> cells = List.from(state.board!.cells);
    Cell cell = Cell(initial: false, value: num);
    cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol] = cell;

    cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol].cellStatus = CellState.none;
    if (num != 0){
      bool isValid = _gameRepository.checkValue(cells, state.selectedRow, state.selectedCol);

      if (!isValid) {
        cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol].cellStatus = CellState.error;
      } 
    }

    Game game = Game(id: state.id,initialBoard: state.initialBoard,board: Board(cells: cells), gameStatus: state.gameStatus, selectedRow: state.selectedRow, selectedCol: state.selectedCol);
    emit(game);
  }
}
```

Para inicializar el cubit y los repositorios uso getit con una clase donde tengo la iyección de dependencias:

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {

//...  
  sl.registerFactory(
  () => GameCubit(
    sl(),
    sl()
    )
  );
//...


}
```

Añado la clase Game

```
enum GameState {
  initial,
  partial,
  completed
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Game extends Equatable {
  String id;
  Board initialBoard;
  Board? board;
  GameState gameStatus;
  int selectedRow;
  int selectedCol;
  // final DateTime time;
  
  Game({required this.id, required this.initialBoard, this.board, required this.gameStatus, required this.selectedRow,required this.selectedCol});

  factory Game.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonDecoded) => _$GameFromJson(jsonDecoded);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$GameToJson(this);
  //editado 2 -->
  Game copyWith({
    String? id,
    Board? initialBoard,
    Board? board,
    GameState? gameStatus,
    int? selectedRow,
    int? selectedCol,
  }) {
    return Game(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      initialBoard: initialBoard ?? this.initialBoard,
      board: board != null ? this.board?.copyWith(board: board.cells) : this.board,
      gameStatus: gameStatus ?? this.gameStatus,
      selectedRow: selectedRow ?? this.selectedRow,
      selectedCol: selectedCol ?? this.selectedCol,
    );
  }
// Editado 2 <--

// Editado -->
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, board, gameStatus];
// Editado <--
}
```

Añado las clases Board y Cell

```
class Board extends Equatable {
  late List<List<Cell>> cells;

  Board({required this.cells});
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [cells];

  Board copyWith({
    List<List<Cell>>? cells
  }) {
    return Board(
      cells: cells ?? this.cells
    );
  }

  factory Board.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonDecoded) => _$BoardFromJson(jsonDecoded);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BoardToJson(this);

}
```

```
enum CellState {
  none,
  selected,
  error
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Cell extends Equatable{
  bool initial;
  int value;
  CellState cellStatus;

  Cell(
      {required this.initial, required this.value, this.cellStatus = CellState.none});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [initial, value, cellStatus];

  factory Cell.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonDecoded) => _$CellFromJson(jsonDecoded);
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CellToJson(this);

}
```

**UPDATE**

Al final he añadido al props del Game las dos variables que modifico:

```
class Game extends Equatable {
  String id;
  Board initialBoard;
  Board? board;
  GameState gameStatus;
  int selectedRow;
  int selectedCol;
  
  Game({required this.id, required this.initialBoard, this.board, required this.gameStatus, required this.selectedRow,required this.selectedCol});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, board, gameStatus, selectedRow, selectedCol];

  factory Game.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonDecoded) => _$GameFromJson(jsonDecoded);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$GameToJson(this);

  Game copyWith({
    String? id,
    Board? initialBoard,
    Board? board,
    GameState? gameStatus,
    int? selectedRow,
    int? selectedCol,
  }) {
    return Game(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      initialBoard: initialBoard ?? this.initialBoard,
      board: board != null ? this.board?.copyWith(cells: board.cells) : this.board,
      gameStatus: gameStatus ?? this.gameStatus,
      selectedRow: selectedRow ?? this.selectedRow,
      selectedCol: selectedCol ?? this.selectedCol,
    );
  }

}
```

En GameCubit cambio la función setPosition por lo siguiente

```
void setPosition(int row, int col){

    _board = state.board!;
    if (state.selectedRow != -1 && state.selectedCol != -1){
      final Cell cell = _board.cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol];
      _board.cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol] =  cell.copyWith(cellStatus:CellState.none);
    }

    final Cell cell = _board.cells[row][col];
    _board.cells[row][col] = cell.copyWith(cellStatus: CellState.selected);
    Game game = state.copyWith(
      board: _board,
      selectedRow: row,
      selectedCol: col
    );

    print(state);
    print(game);
    emit(game);
  }
```

Y por último, la clase Cell, le indico la función copyWith

```
enum CellState {
  none,
  selected,
  error
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Cell extends Equatable{
  bool initial;
  int value;
  CellState cellStatus;

  Cell(
      {required this.initial, required this.value, this.cellStatus = CellState.none});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [initial, value, cellStatus];

  Cell copyWith({
    bool? initial,
    int? value,
    CellState? cellStatus
  }) {
    return Cell(
      initial: initial ?? this.initial,
      value: value ?? this.value,
      cellStatus: cellStatus ?? this.cellStatus
    );
  }

  factory Cell.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonDecoded) => _$CellFromJson(jsonDecoded);
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CellToJson(this);

}
```

Comment: no vemos el método setPosition dentro del GameCubit, es el que llamas :  BlocProvider.of<GameCubit>(context, listen: false)
                  .setPosition(row, col);

Comment: Perdon, justo lo había modificado. Ya esta editado

Comment: por último, podrías agregar como definiste `Game` ? y otra pregunta, cada vez que entra a `setPosition` al emit, te aseguraste de que el objeto emitido es diferente al anterior? le agregaste unos prints para validar? Sabes si logra entrar nuevamente al  builder: (context, game) { del SudokuCell?

Comment: Al poner unos prints he visto que el nuevo game tiene el mismo hasCode, no sé si te refieres a eso con lo de que el objeto emitido sea diferente al anterior. Por último no, no consigue entrar de nuevo al builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de revisar tu clase `Game` veo que no usas el objeto `Board` como parte de los `props` para que pueda generarse un hashcode diferente si los valores del `Board` se actualizan.

Si usas `equatable`, no necesitas esto:

```dart
@override    
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is Game && other.id == id;
```

Solo necesitas definir los `props` de una forma correcta.

En los props, yo añadiría el `board` también, es más, también el `status`.

```dart
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, board, gameStatus];
```

Ahora, recuerda que esas clases también necesitan extender de `Equatable` y también sobreescribir sus `props` para que sepa como comparar el objeto y detectar si hubo un cambio para hacer rebuild.

**UPDATE**

Veo que lo único que cambia es el status del `Cell`, por lo tanto también necesita extender de equatable, si es que aún no lo tienes, y para actualizar el estado necesitarías algo como.

```dart
 if (state.selectedRow != -1 && state.selectedCol != -1){
    final cell = _board.cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol];
   _board.cells[state.selectedRow][state.selectedCol] =  cell.copyWith(cellStatus:CellState.none);
    }
```

El `Cell` debe teber como prop al `cellStatus`.

Otra cosa, a la hora de asignar los cells al board, crea una nueva lista.

```dart
  Board copyWith({
    List<List<Cell>>? cells
  }) {
    return Board(
      cells: List<List<Cell>>.from(cells) ?? this.cells
    );
  }
```

Comment: He añadido las clase Board y Cell. También he modificado los props de las clases como indicas pero sigue sin funcionar.
No entiendo muy bien porque no actualiza el hashCode 
1.- al ser enum GameStatus, tiene que extender de equatable?
2.- al hacer copyWith, debería usar this.board.copyWith(board) para que cambie el objeto?

Gracias por toda la ayuda, indicar que te sigo en tus videos y aprendo bastante de tus indicaciones

Comment: ah, si es enum no es necesario, sí, debes usar el this.board.copyWith

Comment: podrías agregar tu código de como quedaron tus clases? Game, Board  y el método setPosition actualizado

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, sigue sin funcionar, sospecho que no estoy haciendo bien el copyWith

Comment: ya actualicé mi respuesta, necesitas hacer que el objeto mute, para que pueda ser detectado como un cambio en el state y así hacer el rebuild.  Trata de hacer un debug/print antes y después para ver si el objeto Game es diferente

Comment: Al final, añadiendo selectedRow y selectedCol al props de Game si que me cambia el objeto. Con Board parece que copiaba hasta el hashCode... Si tienes alguna otra idea de como hacerlo sin meter en props la fila y la columna, me encantaría leerla!!

Mil gracias igualmente por toda la ayuda!

Comment: lo que necesitas solo es que tu objeto cambie, que sea diferente al anterior estado, revisa bien eso, y en props deben ir las propiedades que tu deseas comparar entre estados.

Comment: Ok, revisare bien porque al hacer el copyWith, no me genera un nuevo objeto. Muchas gracias!